# SQL - how to get the sum of an item on a certain date?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum

I'm writting this code and trying to get the total sum of the inventory on hand for a past date on the store level. RIght now.

```
SELECT 
  --STR_NBR "Store",
  --DAY_DATE "Date",
  b.whse_prod_vendor_nbr,
  PLN_NBR,
  sum(LO_IOH_UNITS)
FROM MSS_OWNER.FCT_IOH_DAY_STR_PLN a, dim_prod_pln b, dim_period c, dim_location d
WHERE a.prod_id = b.prod_id
  and a.per_id = c.per_id
  and a.loc_id = d.str_nbr
  and DAY_DATE >= to_date ('1/19/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
  and (LO_IOH_UNITS) >0
  --and str_nbr in ()
  --and PLN_NBR in ('40000230913')
  and b.whse_prod_vendor_nbr in ('040683')
GROUP BY 
  -- STR_NBR,
  --DAY_DATE,
  b.whse_prod_vendor_nbr,
  PLN_NBR,
```

I do get an answer with this code however the sum is wrong. IF i include Day_date in the select and group part it gives me the sum for each year. I only need it for the past date . If i don't include the date it gives me a wrong sum total for that year...

```
WHSE_PROD_VENDOR_NBR    PLN_NBR SUM(LO_IOH_UNITS)
40683   40000321572 1424
40683   40000323671 63
40683   40000376695 613
40683   40000377705 192146
40683   40000907206 227
40683   40000943394 295018
```

This is what happens if I include the date

```
Date    WHSE_PROD_VENDOR_NBR    PLN_NBR SUM(LO_IOH_UNITS)
2017-01-20 00:00:00 40683   40000321572 204
2017-01-24 00:00:00 40683   40000321572 202
2017-01-19 00:00:00 40683   40000321572 204
2017-01-23 00:00:00 40683   40000321572 204
2017-01-21 00:00:00 40683   40000321572 204
2017-01-22 00:00:00 40683   40000321572 204
2017-01-25 00:00:00 40683   40000321572 202
```

I don't want all the years data only the one years data. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: "... the sum of an item **on a certain date**." ... "For the past date." ... "I don't want all the years data **only the one years data**" ... and in the query you tried, you don't have a condition to select one specific year **or** one specific date, you have `>= <some fixed date>`. There is no way to help you determine what your requirement really is. Please review what you wrote and edit it so it becomes logically consistent with itself (or just explain at the end what you *really* need - I wasn't able to understand).

Comment: yes  you should not include the date in the group by, you can add the date in where clause, by using between  two dates,,,

Comment: It looks like you have a dimensional model to handle inventory tracking. The question is, what is the definition of the grain of your IOH_UNITS. There are several ways to model the inventory. One of the simplest is to use the "quantity on hand". This is what is known as a semi-additive fact. It's find to sum up the IOU_UNITS by product or location, but not by date. For example, if the quantity on hand yesterday is 10 and the quantity on hand today is 10, you cannot sum them up to say the quantity on hand is 20.